# PowerShell Invoke-RestMethod to query Token

Tags: powershell

Am Currently trying to query the authToken

```
$uri = 'http://xxx.centreon/api/index.php?action=authenticate'

$headers = @{
'username' = 'exemple'
'password' = 'exemple'
}
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -Headers $headers  -ContentType application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

But am having bad parameters

```
Via linux : curl -s -d "username=exemple&password=exemple" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -X POST http://xxx.centreon/api/index.php?action=authenticate

{"authToken":"NWU5OWM0YjRhMjIzMDYuMzg2NzYyMDY="}-
```

Comment: What happens? Does `Invoke-RestMethod` throw an error? If so, please post the full error message

Comment: Yes :
Invoke-RestMethod : "Bad parameters"
At line:7 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -Headers $headers  -ContentT ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is a vague question but i do see how things might be wrong.

First the **Username** and **Password** are usually in the **Body** not the **Header**.

In your curl command I see its being passed as -d which would be the **Body**

```
$uri = 'http://xxx.centreon/api/index.php?action=authenticate'

$Body = @{
    'username' = 'exemple'
    'password' = 'exemple'
}

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -body $Body -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

Comment: Invoke-RestMethod $uri -Method Post -Body $headers  -ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'